# Python Matrix multiplication solve Ax <=b

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, matrix-multiplication

not sure how to solve this problem with Python

Have a 3x3 matrix which is A

3x1 matrix (unknown) which is X

and b which is known

How can I find all the solutions which is Ax <= b?  Thanks in advance

Comment: Check out [How to create minimal, complete and verifiable example?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: First reorganize your matrix math so you have all unknowns on one side of the equation...  pretty sure you have to do some matrix math by hand before python can solve this for you.  Is this a homework problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume `A` is invertible. Then you can write the condition

```
Ax <= b
```

as

```
Ax = b + c   |   c <= 0
```

where `c` is a column vector. Since we assumed `A` is invertible we can solve for `x`:

```
x = A^-1 (b + c)
```

Given `c`, `x` will be a solution precisely if all components of `c` are non-positive.

Let's check this using numpy:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>>
# create example A and b
>>> A = np.random.random((3, 3))
>>> b = np.random.random((3, 1))
>>>
# invert A and compute solution for c == 0
>>> invA = np.linalg.inv(A)
>>> x0 = invA @ b
>>> 
# create 10,000 different vectors c
>>> c = np.random.uniform(-10, 10, (3, 10000))
# and mark those which have three non-pos components
>>> all_non_pos = np.all(c <= 0, axis=0)
# compute corresponding vectors x
>>> x = x0 + invA @ c
# and check which are solutions
>>> all_le_b = np.all(A @ x <= b, axis=0)
# finally, check whether solutions correspond to non-neg c 
>>> np.all(all_non_pos == all_le_b)
True
```